# Integrating Bash with PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, debian, echo

Is it possible to integrate the two?

I found this example on the net, but it outputs a blank page. bash on its own is working and outputs Hello World!

bash with 0777 chmod
echo.txt

```
  #!/bin/bash
   echo "Hello World!"
```

PHP

```
<?php
$result=shell_exec("echo.txt");
echo($result);
?>
```

Comment: That Bash script has a syntax error.  Have you tried running it on its own?

Comment: Missing a closing quote in the shell script...

Comment: of course i tried it. blank page.   the bash is fine, just didn't copy/past the "...

Comment: Can you fix your title so that it describes the question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the path to echo.txt, relative to the PHP script or absolute path, and make sure the script is executable.

```
$ chmod +x echo.txt

<?php
$result=shell_exec("./echo.txt");
echo($result);
?>
```

Without specifying the relative path, and running the PHP from the command line, the output was

```
sh: echo.txt: command not found
```

It will work properly with the path specified.

Comment: Thanks. ./ was the missing part

Answer (score 1):

You can also use backticks with php to execute bash scripts directly in php

```
<?php
echo 'this is a php page.';
echo `echo "Hello World!"`;
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure user www-data or whatever user PHP uses has permissions to execute that script.

in UNIX:

```
chgrp www-data echo.txt
chmod 774 echo.txt
```

Comment: He said `777 chmod`, presumably indicating a permission of `0777` on the script file.

Comment: And as Michael pointed out in his answer, you need "./" in front of your path

Comment: So basically you've added nothing at all!

Comment: 777 means: Owner read write execute, group: read write execute, other: read write execute. 774 means the same, but for other: read only. Gives a bit extra security

Comment: yes basically i added nothing at all, i missed the 777 bit, sorry :)